# Server Integrity Check CheckCommands question

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I am trying to figure out what is the best CheckCommands option for ServerIntegrity check.

1. Should I leave the job defaults as is?

   ```
   EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y'
   ```
2. Should i run the `CHECKALLOC,CHECKTABLE,CHECKCATALOG` option separately or is it included in the above? Same for the `CHECKFILEGROUP` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run the base CHECKDB command, you don't need to run the others. The other commands make up what is run by the full command.

See:

- [CHECKDB From Every Angle: Complete description of all CHECKDB stages](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-complete-description-of-all-checkdb-stages/)
- [CHECKDB From Every Angle: Consistency Checking Options for a VLDB](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/)

Breaking the full check into its constituent parts is sometimes done on very large databases where a full check in total is too time consuming or gobbles up too many resources.

The only [CHECKDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) option that results in a different full check (PHYSICAL_ONLY) runs fewer overall checks. It skips logical checks against the data and only checks the physical file structure.

Comment: @eckes Ola's tool run DBCC CHECKDB.

Comment: @eckes okay, cool!